# ASP.NET AJAX Refused to get unsafe header "jsonerror"

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, asp.net-ajax

Using ASP.NET AJAX I am getting the following error in Chrome and Mozilla firefox when I call an asmx webservice with the `[ScriptService]` attribute. It works in IE9...

> Refused to get unsafe header
>   "jsonerror"

Why is the AJAX script manager trying to add/change that header? And how do I stop it?

My javascript:

```
// Asynchronous ajax call to lookup this client
function CallSearch() {
  // Ensure correct SharePoint path is used
  SalesRepSearchWebServices.SalesRepSearchService.set_path(
    "http://localhost:52182/SalesRepSearchService.asmx"
  );

  // Get our txtSearch control
  var txtSearch = document.getElementById("ui_txtSearch");

  // Call web service
  SalesRepSearchWebServices.SalesRepSearchService.GetResults(
    txtSearch.value,
    "All",
    SearchResponse,
    SearchError
  );
}

// Get return value from web service
function SearchResponse(result) {
  alert(result);
  var lblResults = document.getElementById("lblResults");
  lblResults.innerHTML = result;
}

// Display error from web service
function SearchError(result) {
  //alert(result.get_message());
  var lblResults = document.getElementById("lblResults");
  lblResults.innerHTML = result.get_message();
}
```

And a C# snippet:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<Person> GetResults(string input, ResultType resultType)
```

Comment: this may be because browser is perceiving the AJAX request being cross-site. I would suggest that you use tool such as Fiddler to capture both request (and response if any) and post that here so that others can help you.

Comment: So did you find an answer to this? I am having a very similar issue only it only manifests on iPhone/iPad

Comment: It's now 2017 and I am seeing this in Chrome's console.  The error is not reported in my code but in: MicrosoftAjax.debug.js:6091